# Sql nested queries execution performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, subquery

Following is my nested SQL query:

```
SELECT M.UserID, SUM(M.Browser)
FROM
(
    SELECT UserID, X.Browser
    FROM
    (
        SELECT UserName, PCMLogEventID, MAX(Browser) AS Browser
        FROM [PCMDBSERVER].[MISTestPCM_Raw].[dbo].[PCM_Log_FilterSwitchData] 
        WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN '6/12/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND '6/12/2013 11:59:59 PM'
        GROUP BY UserName, PCMLogEventID
    ) X
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM PCM_Stat_UserRepository 
        WHERE MachineID='All' 
    ) Y
    ON X.UserName = Y.UserName
) M
GROUP BY M.UserID
```

The execution time for the inner query -with the select clause (Select UserID, X.Browser), only takes 1 second to execute, returning just 197 rows. However when I execute the entire nested query it take almost 6 minutes to return the result. Could anyone help me understand why does it take such a long time ?

EDIT:
Actually PCMLogEventID is needed. Because the data in PCM_Log_FilterSwitchData is something like this:
UserName    | PCMLogEventID | Browser
abc | 111       | 0.9
abc | 111       | 1.2
abc | 222       | 1.2
abc | 222       | 3.5
.
.
Thus i'm first taking the MAX by grouping UserName & PCMLogEventID, and then the SUM of it.

Comment: `[PCM_Log_FilterSwitchData]` is a view? And why you `GROUP BY PCMLogEventID`?

Comment: In case of inner queries, for each row returned by outer query, inner query gets executed. Hence, even if your inner query takes just a few seconds to execute, the outer query might be returning many rows, resulting in multiple executions of the inner query.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta, I not agree with you - everything depends on the `Execution Plan`.

Comment: Sub query processing is explained here.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries008.htm

Comment: Is that `[PCMDBSERVER].[MISTestPCM_Raw].[dbo].[PCM_Log_FilterSwitchData]` on a different server?  And can you confirm the SQL Sever tag that someone added?

Comment: Fully agree with @Mark Schultheiss.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, PCM_Log_FilterSwitchData is on another server of which I have created a linked server.

Comment: Reason I ask is that sometimes a remote server query does a full table scan and this would process that sub query multiple times due to the construct of it - hence why a temp table with results might enhance performance for those 197 rows - do it once not multiple times.  I encourage you to look at the actual execution plan in SSMS on this one.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. I have changed the order: First MAX, then SUM, and then JOIN.

```
    Select Y.UserID, P.Browser
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT X.UserName, SUM(X.Browser) as Browser
        FROM
        (
            SELECT UserName, PCMLogEventID, MAX(Browser) AS Browser
            FROM [PCMDBSERVER].[MISTestPCM_Raw].[dbo].[PCM_Log_FilterSwitchData] 
            WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN '6/12/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND '6/12/2013 11:59:59 PM'
            GROUP BY UserName, PCMLogEventID
        ) X
        GROUP BY X.UserName
        ) P
        INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT * FROM PCM_Stat_UserRepository WHERE MachineID='All' ) Y
    ON P.UserName = Y.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT M.UserID, Browser = SUM(X.Browser)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
          UserName
        , Browser = MAX(Browser) 
    FROM [PCMDBSERVER].[MISTestPCM_Raw].[dbo].[PCM_Log_FilterSwitchData] 
    WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN '20130613 12:00:00' AND '20130613 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY UserName
) X
JOIN (
    SELECT 
          UserName
        , UserID 
    FROM dbo.PCM_Stat_UserRepository 
    WHERE MachineID = 'All' 
) M ON X.UserName = Y.UserName
GROUP BY M.UserID
```

Comment: This is mostly where I was taking my thoughts also.  The other possibility would be to put the sub select for `[PCM_Log_FilterSwitchData]` result into a temp table and simply join that to the second one forgoing the outer select perhaps.

Comment: That seems to be working @Devart, but could you help me explain how simply replacing Inner Join with Join did the magic ?

Comment: But you missed PCMLogEventID, @Devart !

Comment: The main magic - query without grouping by `PCMLogEventID` column. `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` are equal.